# Is finding arbitrary-but-fixed length cycles in a graph NP-Hard?

Tags: graphs, np

My intuition says yes. I think so because if we could find arbitrary length cycles, couldn't we just look for an n length cycle and then solve **HAM-CYCLE**? But I saw a [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16393/finding-a-cycle-of-fixed-length) that seems to suggest a polynomial time method for finding cycles! I feel as if perhaps I do not understand something here.

Comment: Notice that the length of the cycle, `k`, is not part of their time estimates.

Comment: Ah! I see, so if the k were to be included, we would have a non-polynomial runtime?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Converting it into an answer?

Comment: See [this answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19510/12739).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithms mentioned are all [fixed-parameter tractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) in the size of the cycle.  This means that if you fix the cycle size $k$, there's a polynomial time algorithm for finding the cycle as the number of vertices or edges increases, but the run time still increases exponentially as $k$ increases.  The big-O notation you're looking at only specifies asymptotic run times as the number of edge and vertices increase, but leaves out the possibly large but constant $k!$ factor.

Comment: This actually helps a lot. So this means that even when a runtime has a constant factor but one that is exponential or factorial in size, the problem becomes NP-Hard?

Comment: No, the notational confusion has no bearing on whether the problem is NP-hard or not.  The key thing to understand is that search problems can have multiple parameters and be exponentially difficult (or worse) measured against some parameters and only polynomially difficult in others.  Whether the problem is NP-hard is a separate issue.  A paper like "Finding Even Cycles Even Faster" assumes a high-level audience for whom the NP-hardness and fixed parameter tractability of HAM-CYCLE, and the limitations of big-O notation need no mentioning.